# Автоматизация добавления данных в базу MS Access

Tags: python, access, form, автоматизация

Есть база MS Access с готовыми формами, таблицей. Каким образом можно автоматизировать внесение данных в таблицу или в формы с помощью python или другого языка. Данные необходимо вносить с текстового файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ написать скрипт на родном VBA MS Access, который будет парсить Ваш файл. Можно парсить файл на другом языке и передавать данные через ODBC